# count no. of 1s and 0s without comparing

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

In an array of only 1's and 0's how would you count no. of 1s and 0s without comparing and then modify it to array of 3s and 5s.
My approach is to use cumulative array such that cumulative[i]=array[i]+cumulative[i-1]. No of one=cumulative[n] number of zeroes =n-cumulative[n]; 
Is this approach correct ? Or suggest some other approach ? 
Can we convert it into array's of 3's and 5's  without comparing?

Comment: Use an associative dictionary and just use the numbers as keys, defaulting the value in the dictionary to 0 for new elements.

Comment: Will the array contain *both* 3's and 5's? Or only 0's and one non-0 number? ie. 0's and 3's, or 0's and 5's, or ... ?

Comment: What about adding all values and subtracting that from the length/number of elements? It should not be difficult to see the approach doesn't need to change much for an arbitrary pair of values known at start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is correct. I also don't think it can be improved much - after all you need to iterate over all array elements.

Comment: Can we convert it into array's of 3's and 5's  without comparing?

Comment: well you can do something of the sort of `new_array[i] = old_array[i] * 2 + 3`. Note that this approach will only make sense for practice - it does not optimize anything and it reduces readability

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this without using comparisons by relying on the fact that `0` is treated as `False` in most languages and `1` is treated as `True`. 
Example: C, Python.

So, instead of comparing whether the value is 0 or 1, just use it as the conditional directly, and you should be able to do the job without comparison. You can use the same to count the occurances of `1`, and `0`.

In Python, this will translate into the following code

```
>>> original_list = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> altered_list = [3 if item else 5 for item in original_list]
>>> print altered_list
[5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5]
```

Comment: These are still comparisons - even though they use implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact that you *only* have ones and zeroes and also for any item it's true that *item plus "one minus item" yields "one"*. So to count number of each you can use:

```
numOfOnes += item[i];
numOfZeroes += (1 - item[i]);
```

Then your next problems is you have to somehow convert zeroes into 5s and ones into 3s. Use the same trick as above - a weighted sum of *number* and *one minus number* such that it yields 3s and 5s respectively. You'll have to figure out the right weight values.

Positively no comparisons. And as a bonus you can do all of that in one pass - convert values and count them on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use counting sort method technique: Create another array of size 2, say b[2]. Then do this:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
b[a[i]]++;
}
```

Finally, b[0] will have the count of number of zeroes, and b[1] will have number of 1s.

Answer (score 0):

to convert 0->3 and 1->5 you can use lookup table

```
const int lookup[]={3,5};

forloop {
   array[i] = lookup[array[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//To find the count of 0 & 1 we can do below 
public void findZeroOneCount(int [] arr){
        int len=arr.length;
        System.out.println(len);
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            sum=sum+arr[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Count of Zero:"+(len-sum%len));
        System.out.println("Count of One:"+sum%len);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution a little, outside of code block